# "not authorized to execute this request" using the arangodb java driver

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, arangodb

I want to use the java driver for ArangoDB in a Maven project on Eclipse. I am trying to follow the tutorial for the java driver for ArangoDB available [here](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver), but I cannot even get the simpler application to work, even starting from a clean project.

*main.java:*

```
package test;

import com.arangodb.ArangoDB;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().build();

        arangoDB.createDatabase("myDatabase");
    }

}
```

*pom.xml:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
   <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arangodb-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I get the following error when running the code:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 401, Error: 11 - not authorized to execute this request
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.checkError(VstCommunication.java:106)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:134)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:46)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.execute(VstCommunication.java:96)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstProtocol.execute(VstProtocol.java:46)
    at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:58)
    at com.arangodb.ArangoDB.createDatabase(ArangoDB.java:437)
    at test.main.main(main.java:12)
```

---

I tried other basic operations, none work (even a simple `arangoDB.getVersion();`).

---

If I add the following dependency to the pom.xml, it removes warnings but not the errors:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 401, Error: 11 - not authorized to execute this request
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.checkError(VstCommunication.java:106)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:134)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:46)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.execute(VstCommunication.java:96)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstProtocol.execute(VstProtocol.java:46)
    at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:58)
    at com.arangodb.ArangoDB.createDatabase(ArangoDB.java:437)
    at test.main.main(main.java:12)
```

Comment: In my understanding, receiving a `Response: 401` indicates that the credentials provided (or not) are not enough to perform the query on the target database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify connection data to your db like user, password and etc, all what is db need to succesfully connection, check again javadoc of class 
[Builder](https://arangodb.github.io/arangodb-java-driver/javadoc-4_0/index.html) and set user and password.

```
ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().build();
```

Here you setup nothing and build `ArrangoDb` instance without any connection data at all

Comment: So, I actually followed [this tutorial](https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/tutorial-sync-java-driver/) in which no user name is given.

Comment: I partially solved the problem by setting the user: `ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().user("root").build();`.
Now the operations of creating, databases, collections and documents work, but attempting to read an existing document yields a NullPointerException.

Comment: I get this error following the tutorial I just mentioned, or trying to use some code that previously worked when I compiled the Java driver myself, but not anymore since I tried to use Maven.