# ArangoDB with Python - 401 not authorized to execute this request

Tags: python, database, arangodb

I am currently trying to **create and populate** a collection automatically via Python. As mentioned the DB that I've chosen is **Arango**. The issue that I am having is that I get an error:

> [HTTP 401][ERR 11] not authorized to execute this request

I've turned off fire walls and tried reinstalling Arango to check if I messed up something with setting up the admin profile but everything seems to be fine. The only similar question I've found so far is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775333/not-authorized-to-execute-this-request-using-the-arangodb-java-driver) but it's still somehow irrelevant to my issue.

In regards to the builder, this is how I've set it up:

```
config={
   "database": 'exampleDB',
   "host":'localhost',
   "protocol":'http',
   "port":'8529',
   "username":'someone',
   "password":'xxxx'
}
```

Is there anything else that I am missing for setting up the permissions config? Or the issue might be somewhere else.

*I am not posting my full code because it's company owned software.*

Comment: You need to share more details. What kind of request fails? Has the user access to the databases / collections he wants to query?

Comment: @JanChristophUhde The user does have access to the database. I'm using my admin account for this. The collections are non existent, I am trying to create a collection automatically from python

Comment: Would you please create a minimal working sample that reproduces the issue? What version of ArangoDB are you using? Do you use  pyarango or arango-python?

Comment: I am using pyarango and arango-python. The Verson of the database is 3.3.17. I'm about to create a similar code snippet. I'll edit the question in 1-2 hours.

Answer (score 5):

In case of [**pyArango**](https://github.com/tariqdaouda/pyArango) you need to provide the credentials when you instantiate the Connection class:

```
from pyArango.connection import *
conn = Connection(username=config['username'], password=config['password'])
```

Documentation: https://bioinfo.iric.ca/~daoudat/pyArango/connection.html

In case of [**python-arango**](https://github.com/joowani/python-arango) you first need a client object, then call the `db()` method and provide the database name and the credentials:

```
from arango import ArangoClient
client = ArangoClient(protocol='http', host='localhost', port=8529)
db = client.db('_system', username=config['username'], password=config['password'])
```

Documentation: https://python-driver-for-arangodb.readthedocs.io/en/master/overview.html

The original repository of [arango-python](https://github.com/joymax/arango-python) is abandoned since five years, it does not support any 2.x or 3.x server versions and I could not find anything for authentication (search on GitHub yielded no results for "auth", "password", "user", "cred"). The [docs site](https://arangodb-python-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is even more stale.

The [ArangoPy](https://github.com/saeschdivara/ArangoPy) project appears to be pretty dead as well, it supports ArangoDB 2.2 through 2.6 according to the readme. There is no example given for authentication. The [Client constructor](https://github.com/saeschdivara/ArangoPy/blob/master/arangodb/api.py) does take a parameter called `auth`, but the usage remains unclear (`<username>:<password>`?).

Comment: I am having a similar situation running the database in a production environment when running the `system_db.has_database` method. As for the part where you say the documentation/repo of `python-arango` being abandoned it really isn't, it's still active here https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/python-arango, which still has a commit 2 days ago.

Comment: @LibbyLebyane The `arango-python` driver by joymax / mklymyshyn driver is dead. The `python-arango` driver by joowani is maintained and got moved to the ArangoDB-Community organization.

Comment: Oh yeah, a point made clear! Just new to ArangoDB and not really familiar with its history.

Comment: Have an idea of what might be causing the errors? Cause seems to work on my development environment but not in a docker image.

Comment: It would be best if you asked that as a separate question because it seems more related to Docker than the driver. You should include the commands you use to start the container etc.